\footcite losing reference section numbering
I'm using a footcite hack I found here: Biblatex, Footnote Citations and Numbers in Bibliography (which is pretty out of date, but ...)
Specifically, here's what I have (in overleaf):
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authortitle-icomp,bibstyle=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
%  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}% DELETED
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}% NEW
  \csxdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@footnotenumber}{\the\value{footnote}}% NEW
}% NEW

The footcite part works fine, however (a) I'm getting this error: "Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'cite:full' undefined. Using \newbibmacro", which I assume is self-correcting. The more important problem (b) is that the references have no number! Per:

Thanks in advance for your help.
Here's the MRE code:
blah.tex:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authortitle-icomp,bibstyle=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}%
\csxdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@footnotenumber}{\the\value{footnote}}%
}% NEW

\DeclareFieldFormat{prefixnumber}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\csuse{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}@footnotenumber}}

\bibliography{blah.bib}
\title{blah blah}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

``blah blah blahblah blah blah''\footcite{AT50Mind}

\section{blah blah}
blah blah blah.\footcite[25-30]{C&G64}
\section{blah blah}
blahblah blah blahblah blah blahbla\footcite[12]{BBNHistory}

blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blah\footcite[25-30]{AT50Mind}

\printbibliography
\end{document}


blah.bib:
@misc{ADA43,
  author = {Ada Augusta, Countess of Lovelace},
  title = {Notes on L. F. Menabrea’s “Sketch of the Analytical Engine Invented by Charles Babbage”},
  journal = {Scientific Memoirs},
  month = 9,
  year = {1843},
  howpublished = {\url{http://imaginaryinstruments.org/lovelace-analytical-engine/}},
  note = {Accessed 2022-11-04}
}

@article{ARSTech2022Alexa,
  title = {Amazon Alexa is a “colossal failure,” on pace to lose \$10 billion this year},
  journal = {Ars Technica},
  howpublished = {\url{https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/11/amazon-alexa-is-a-colossal-failure-on-pace-to-lose-10-billion-this-year/}},
  note = {Accessed 2022-11-27}
}

@article{AT50Mind,
  author = {Turing, A},
  title = {Computing Machinery and Intelligence},
  journal = {Mind},
  volume = {49},
  pages = {433-460},
  year = {1950}
}

@book{BBNHistory,
  editor = {Walden, D and Nickerson, R},
  title = {A Culture of Innovation: Insider Accounts of Computing and Life at BBN},
  publisher = {Waterside Publishing},
  year = {201},
  note = {A Sixty Year Report 18 October 1948 to 1 July 2010}
}

@article{C&G64,
  author = {Colby, KM and Gilbert, JP},
  title = {Programming a computer model of neurosis},
  journal = {J. Math Psych},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {405-416},
  year = {1964}
}


Welcome to TeX.SE. It would make our lives a lot simpler if you can provide a full, compilable example showing your problem that we can just copy and paste to debug and troubleshoot. In your case this will probably include both a simple tex file with a complete preamble, some example uses of the \footcite macro, together with a bib file.

Thanks, @WillieWong. Done. Ps. The spec I'm trying to meet is for IEEE Annals of History of Computing, and it's really weird. They want footcites and alphabetic authors in the refs, but sequential ref numbers!

I am pretty sure you are misreading their citation format. They want the bibliography to be sorted by author name, and numbered sequentially within the bibliography. They allow both footnote and bracket style citations. The footnote number need not correlate with the sequence number of the bibliography. Indeed, in a footnote citation the sequence number is optional, but recommended if you decide to mix footnote citations together with inline citations.

I am pretty sure just a simple \usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=verbose,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex} without any additional customization will satisfy the requirements of the author guidelines. In fact, clicking on a few random papers in that journal, I haven't yet seen one that uses \footcite; most just use inline citations.
